# Can I use \clap, \rlap and \llap in math mode?

Tags: macros, math-mode

The commands `\clap`, `\llap` and `\rlap` are useful "horizontal" analogues of `\smash`: they reduce the horizontal width of a box to zero, aligning the box with either the middle, left or right of the typeset contents. Unfortunately they don't work in math mode.

> Can someone suggest a math mode macro that has the effect of `\clap` and friends?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package contains (among other useful things) the implementations of `\mathclap` and relatives from Andrew's answer.

Comment: That _should_ have come up in my search!  Strange that it did not.  Thanks for filling in.

Comment: I need examples in the use of the clpa command, rlap and llap cause no issues, but I cannot use clap command in the same  manner.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if they are implemented in a specific package (search CTAN), but there's an article in TUGBoat, (TUGboat 22 (2001), 350–352.) that gives an implementation.  Here's the article on the author's website:

http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/

I suspect that anyone putting this in a package would have used the same names, or at least referred to this article, so searching on CTAN for the command names used there would be a reasonable thing to do.

(Breadcrumb trail: I first learnt of this via [this blog post](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/itex2MMLcommands.html) about these commands in iTeX.)

(I'm feeling generous: I just tried the obvious searches on CTAN and nothing came up; so based on that, you should copy the definitions from that article.)

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, in ConTeXt `\rlap` etc do the right thing in math mode as well. They are defined as

```
\unexpanded\def\rlap{\mathortext\domathrlap\dorlap}
\unexpanded\def\llap{\mathortext\domathllap\dollap}
\unexpanded\def\clap{\mathortext\domathclap\doclap}
```

where `\domathrlap` and `\dorlap` are roughly equivalent to LaTeX's `\mathrlap` and `\rlap`.