# How to make overlaid text?

Tags: characters, text-manipulation, soul

Is there a nice way to overlay text in the space of one character?

So if text is overlaid as I described it would almost result in a black square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `soul`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{\rlap{\the\SOUL@token}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\stack}[1]{%
  \let\space\relax% no space desired
  \so{#1}}
\begin{document}
\stack{S}

\stack{So}

\stack{So if this text}

\stack{So if this text is stacked as I described it would almost result to a black square.}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacking characters]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but in my case the text is input from a file. Like `\stack{\input{Text}}` but this results to File not found error.

Comment: @user7630: You did not mention this in your question. However, in order to avoid mixing topics, I suggest posting a follow-up question such as "How can I use `\input` within arguments" or "... within `soul` arguments".

Comment: I think I'll do that

Answer (score 4):

this is kind of kludgy, and can be handled more elegantly as a loop, but i'll leave that
nicety to someone else.

```
\rlap{a}\rlap{b}\rlap{c}\rlap{d}...z
```

(where `z` is the final glyph in the string) will have the effect of setting the successive glyphs on top of one another.  (i interpret that as what you mean by "stack", rather than setting the glyphs as a "tower" with one *above* the other.)

Comment: The [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides similar macros to `\rlap`, `\llap` and `\clap` in math mode: `\mathrlap`, `\mathllap` and `\mathclap`. See this post: [Can I use \clap, \rlap and \llap in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278/5764) or consider reading [A complement to `\smash`, `\llap`, and `\rlap`](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/).