# How could I use \input within soul arguments?

Tags: input, soul

So, I basically want to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\so{Hello}

\so{\input{key.tex}}

\end{document}
```

Now the first "so" works but the second does not. It does not find the file no matter how I specify the file location. Why does this not work and how could I fix it? Perhaps modifying the soul source code but what should I modify?

I would rather use the soul to do this because this is continuation from [How to make overlaid text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27357/how-to-make-overlaid-text).

Comment: A caveat: if the file 'key.tex' contains more than one paragraph and the content goes over a page break then page numbering can fail (see, for example, [Bug with page numbers when using `soul`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25250/bug-with-page-numbers-when-using-soul-package])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `soul` package scans its argument and doesn't typeset it directly, therefore the content isn't inserted by `\input`. You need to read the file content manually and feed it to `\so` (or any other `soul` macro). This can be done easily using the `catchfile` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef\filecontent{key.tex}{}
\expandafter\so\expandafter{\filecontent}

\end{document}
```

If you need this more often define a macro for this:

```
\newcommand{\soinput}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \CatchFileDef\filecontent{#1}{}%
    \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\so\expandafter{\filecontent}%
}
% ...
\soinput{key}
```

Note: The group is there to keep the assignment of `\filecontent` local and avoid any name clash if this macro is used somewhere else.

Comment: This works in the example perfectly but when added to the document I get an error: `! Argument of � has an extra }.` for the `\expandafter\so\expandafter{\filecontent}` line. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have special characters in the file name? Without more knowledge of your document it isn't easy to tell what is wrong. Try to only use `\filecontent` and see if the error disappears, so we know if it is the `\so` or the `\filecontent`.

Comment: It should not have any special characters and I can't find the � character anywhere. `\expandafter\so\expandafter{test}` works but everything else seems to fail. The filename actually is key.tex

Comment: In this case try to minimize your document and upload it somewhere so I can have a look on it.