# Using \input within \textcite{}

Tags: biblatex

I have a file called `Test.tex` containting

```
ID1
```

I'm trying to feed this file to a `\textcite{}` command, using the `input{}`command.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{ID1,
    Author = {Some Author},
    Journal = {Some Journal},
    Title = {Some Title},
    Year = {2016},
    Volume = {1(1)},
    Pages = {1-10}}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{\input{./Test.tex}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Running this gives me the following error:

```
! Argument of \blx@citeargs@i has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.15 ^^I\textcite{\input{./Test.tex}}
```

Looking at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27433/how-could-i-use-input-within-soul-arguments) thread, I tried going around the problem by using

```
\begin{filecontents*}{References.bib}
@article{ID1,
    Author = {Some Author},
    Journal = {Some Journal},
    Title = {Some Title},
    Year = {2016},
    Volume = {1(1)},
    Pages = {1-10}}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
\CatchFileDef\filecontent{Test.tex}{}
\expandafter\textcite\expandafter{\filecontent}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This didn't completely solve my problem though. The reference list came out alright, but the in text citation just read `ID1` instead of `Author (2016)`.

Comment: Why do you want to rread a bibkey from a file?

Comment: @Johannes_B This is just a made up example (that's smaller for clarity). In reality, "Test.txt" contains a couple of hundred references that should be included using the `\nocite` command.

Comment: Extract the needed entries in a separate file and use `\nocite{*}`, or create a set and cite that.

Comment: @Johannes_B Doing something like that seems like quite a mess to me. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170316/nocite-for-single-bibdatasources-with-biblatex-biber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting to say `\endlinechar=-1`. If you look in the log file, you'll find

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'ID1 ' on page 1 undefined on input line 23.
```

that accounts for the problem, due to the space added at the end of the line. With `\endlinechar=-1`, no end-of-line character is added.

In the example I used `\jobname` not to clobber my files.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ID1,
    Author = {Some Author},
    Journal = {Some Journal},
    Title = {Some Title},
    Year = {2016},
    Volume = {1(1)},
    Pages = {1-10}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.key}
ID1
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef\filecontent{\jobname.key}{\endlinechar=-1 }
\textcite{\filecontent}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note that `\expandafter` is not needed.

[image]