# Alignment using an alignat{2} environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, alignat

In the following code, I have the appropriate alignment. All the equal signs are aligned. There is one expression that is written on two lines; I wanted the first plus signs aligned. I used an `aligned[t]` environment to get this. How do I get this using an `alignat{2}` environment?

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,landscape]{amsart}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}

\noindent $a = x_{1} + iy_{1}$ and $z = x_{2} + iy_{2}$.
\begin{align*}
\big\vert 1 - \overline{a}z \big\vert^{2} &= \big\vert 1 - x_{1}x_{2} - y_{1}y_{2} + i(x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}) \big\vert^{2} \\
&= \begin{aligned}[t]1 &+ {x_{1}}^{2}{x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2} \\
&+ {x_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2}{y_{1}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2}
\end{aligned} \\
&= \begin{aligned}[t]1 + {x_{1}}^{2}{x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + {x_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2}{y_{1}}^{2}
\end{aligned} \\
&= \begin{aligned}[t]1 + ({x_{1}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}) ({x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{2}}^{2}) - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} ,
\end{aligned}
\intertext{and}
\vert z - a \vert^{2} &= \mathmakebox[0pt][l]{\vert x_{2} - x_{1} + i(y_{2} - y_{1}) \vert^{2}} \\
&= {x_{1}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2} + {y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be much too complicated to use `alignat`. Actually you only need one `aligned` environment. Note the `\!` to have an exact (first)  alignment.

I don't see the necessity of aligning the `+` signs of the second and third lines of the alignment. I prefer aligning differently, so as to show clearly the third line is the continuation of the second ; I also made a  smaller vertical spacing between these lines,  thus making, in my opinion, the equations more readable.

If you want to use `alignat` it will be more complex — it wil be alignat`{3}` and a number of `\rlap` commands:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,landscape]{amsart}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}

\noindent $a = x_{1} + iy_{1}$ and $z = x_{2} + iy_{2}$.
\begin{align*}
\big\vert 1 - \overline{a}z \big\vert^{2} &= \big\vert 1 - x_{1}x_{2} - y_{1}y_{2} + i(x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}) \big\vert^{2} \\
&=\!\begin{aligned}[t]1 + x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}+ y_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} &- 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2} \\[-0.5ex]
  & + x_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}y_{1}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2}
 \end{aligned}
 \\
&=1  + x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2} + y_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + x_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}y_{1}^{2}
 \\
&= 1 + (x_{1}^{2} + y_{1}^{2}) (x_{2}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}) - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} ,
\intertext{and}
\vert z - a \vert^{2} &= \mathmakebox[0pt][l]{\vert x_{2} - x_{1} + i(y_{2} - y_{1}) \vert^{2}} \\
&= x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} .
\end{align*}\vskip1cm

With an \texttt{alignat} environment,  it is much more complex: 
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\big\lvert 1 - \overline{a}z \big\rvert^{2} &= \mathrlap{\big\lvert 1   - x_{1}x_{2} - y_{1}y_{2}{}+ i(x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}) \big\rvert^{2}} \\
&= 1& &{}  + x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}+ y_{1}^{2} y_{2}^{2}  &  &{} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2} \\[-0.5ex]
  & &  & &  &    + x_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}y_{1}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2}
 \\
&=1 &&{} + \mathrlap{x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2} + y_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + x_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}y_{1}^{2}}
 \\
&=1& &{}+ \mathrlap{(x_{1}^{2} + y_{1}^{2}) (x_{2}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}) - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} ,}
\intertext{and}
\vert z - a \vert^{2} &= \mathrlap{\vert x_{2} - x_{1} + i(y_{2} - y_{1}) \vert^{2}} \\
&=\mathrlap{ x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2}.}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to use the alignat environment to familiarize myself with it. As you saw from my code, I got the proper alignment using the aligned environment within the align environment. (I did forget to add the "\!" before the aligned environment.) Please give me your display using the alignat environment.

Comment: I'll do that in a moment., but I must warn you it will be more complicated.

Comment: @user60254: Iadded a solution with `alignat{3}` that I wouldn't advise…

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to use the `alignat` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- Replaced the `\intertext` with `\shortintertext` as I think that looks better when you have very small text as it adds less vertical space before and after the text.
- Used `\mathrlap` to ensure that portions of some lines did not affect the alignment in the other lines.
- Aligned as many of the binary operators as I thought made sense without reorganizing the terms of the equations, or that did not leave too much blank space. Adjust this as desired.
- Since _each `&` provides a `r` and `l` alignment point, double `&&` are used for all subsequent alignment points so that the text following the `&&` is left aligned.

### References:

- [Can I use \clap, \rlap and \llap in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278/can-i-use-clap-rlap-and-llap-in-math-mode) especially the link in one of the answers: [A complement to \smash, \llap, and \rlap](http://math.arizona.edu/%7Eaprl/publications/mathclap/)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,landscape]{amsart}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}

\noindent $a = x_{1} + iy_{1}$ and $z = x_{2} + iy_{2}$.
\begin{alignat*}{7}
\big\vert 1 - \overline{a}z \big\vert^{2} 
&= \big\vert &&1 &&- x_{1}x_{2} - y_{1}y_{2} + \mathrlap{i(x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}) \big\vert^{2}} \\
&= && 1 &&+ {x_{1}}^{2}{x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2}  &&- 2y_{1}y_{2}  &&+ 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2} \\
& && &&+ {x_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2}{y_{1}}^{2}  && &&- 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2}  \\
&= && 1 &&+ {x_{1}}^{2}{x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2}  &&- 2y_{1}y_{2} &&+ {x_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2}{y_{1}}^{2} \\
&= && 1 &&+ ({x_{1}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}) ({x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{2}}^{2}) &&- 2x_{1}x_{2} &&- 2y_{1}y_{2} ,
\shortintertext{and}% <--- Replaced \intertext
\vert z - a \vert^{2} &= \mathrlap{\vert x_{2} - x_{1} + i(y_{2} - y_{1}) \vert^{2}} \\
&= \mathrlap{{x_{1}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2} + {y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2}} .
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I adapted your code to the alignments that I had. Thanks.  How is "and" displayed differently using the \intertext and \shortintertext commands?  How does "\mathrlap{}" in the first line of code keep the alignment?  I compiled the code without it and the display had the "1" aligned but they were aligned about an inch from the equal signs.

Comment: @user60254: Updated answer to attempt to answer your questions. If still not clear, might be useful to have a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which doesn't used an environment:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,landscape]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent $a = x_{1} + iy_{1}$ and $z = x_{2} + iy_{2}$.
\begin{align*}
\big\vert 1 - \overline{a}z \big\vert^{2} &= \big\vert 1 - x_{1}x_{2} - y_{1}y_{2} + i(x_{1}y_{2} - x_{2}y_{1}) \big\vert^{2} \\
&= 1 + {x_{1}}^{2}{x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2} \\
&\phantom{{}=1} + {x_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2}{y_{1}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2}y_{1}y_{2}\\
&= 1 + {x_{1}}^{2}{x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} + {x_{1}}^{2}{y_{2}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2}{y_{1}}^{2}\\
&= 1 + ({x_{1}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2}) ({x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{2}}^{2}) - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} ,
\intertext{and}
\vert z - a \vert^{2} &= \vert x_{2} - x_{1} + i(y_{2} - y_{1}) \vert^{2} \\
&= {x_{1}}^{2} + {x_{2}}^{2} + {y_{1}}^{2} + {y_{2}}^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} - 2y_{1}y_{2} .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have a lot of parentheses which are not really needed. Here is my way:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,landscape]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent $a = x_1 + iy_1$ and $z = x_2 + iy_2$.
\begin{align*}
\left| 1 - \overline{a}z \right|^2 &= \left| 1 - x_1x_2 - y_1y_2 + i\left(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1\right) \right|^2 \\
&= 1 + x_1^2x_2^2 + y_1^2y_2^2 - 2x_1x_2 - 2y_1y_2 + 2x_1x_2y_1y_2 \\
&\phantom{{}=1} + x_1^2y_2^2 + x_2^2y_1^2 - 2x_1x_2y_1y_2\\
&= 1 + x_1^2x_2^2 + y_1^2y_2^2 - 2x_1x_2 - 2y_1y_2 + x_1^2y_2^2 + x_2^2y_1^2\\
&= 1 + \left(x_1^2 + y_1^2\right) \left(x_2^2 + y_2^2\right) - 2x_1x_2 - 2y_1y_2 ,
\shortintertext{and}
\left| z - a \right|^2 &= \left| x_2 - x_1 + i\left(y_2 - y_1\right) \right|^2 \\
&= x_1^2 + x_2^2 + y_1^2 + y_2^2 - 2x_1x_2 - 2y_1y_2 .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not expect "&\phantom{{}=1}" to give the alignment of the plus signs in the one expression that is written on two lines. The previous line starts with "= 1 + x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2}" and the following line starts with "+ x_{1}^{2} y_{2}^{2}". The alignment marker is at "=". I would expect that "\phantom{{}=1}" would move the "+" only to the right of "1" but it moves the "+" to the right of "1" and the extra space on either side of a binary operator.